# Referencing external XSLT libraries in OSB

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces, osb

An Oracle Service Bus 12c Project uses XSL transformation, and in it, some exsl.org functions. So the namespace is included in the xsl file like this:

xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"

Then, the XSL is trying to use one of them exsl functions like this:

xsl:value-of select="count(exsl:node-set($temp)/g:W)">

As we can see from the Weblogic log, it just doesn't work:
XML-22015: (Error) Function 'http://exslt.org/common:node-set' not found.

We've had similar problems before and the solution was to change the namespace. For example, we were only able to use the java format method by declaring the following namespace (I'm omitting the http since stackoverflow doesn't like it):
www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java.text.Format
and it didn't work like this: www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform

So I wonder what the correct namespace is for node-set or how to find it out for future cases. Our system does not have internet connection, so I suspect these libraries are stored somewhere and these namespaces serve as keys for some mappings anyway, pointing to some offline location (?)

Comment: Can you run http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest.xml in your environment to find out which XSLT processor is used? As an alternative, try whether the expression works without the use of the `exsl:node-set` function, i.e. whether `<xsl:value-of select="count($temp/g:W)">` works.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Well, I cannot test that file, as no external drives are allowed, so no file transfer is possible. Maybe I'll type it in, if I have the time. I tried the code without the node-set and then its problem is that it cannot create the nodeset.

Comment: @Martin Honnen       Martin, I ran your xml and it gives me output based on the browser I use. Only the xsl version is 1 in all cases.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know anything about OSB and how it uses XSLT, if you run that test XSLT in the browser then I would your code using `exsl:node-set` assume to work in Firefox and Chrome and Opera, but not in IE. Hopefully someone more familiar with OSB and its use of XSLT can help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the solution was not to use nodeset altogether. Tree fragment to nodeset conversions are implicit in XSLT 2.0, so I simply needed to change the version to 2.0 an omit the nodeset function.